# Gap Above Bottom Tab Bar - Embedded NavigationController + Embedded TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, layout

This issue has had me stumped for a few days.

This is my relevant storyboard layout:
[image]
I have set every layout under the sun to all three View Controllers and still get a resultant Table View with a "gap" above the Banner View - seemingly the same height as the Banner View. As follows:

[image]

One thing that did work was to drag the Container View over the bottom Banner View like this:

[image]

And the result renders perfectly on my test device as well as every simulator - i.e. no gap.

But such a solution is essentially a hack of sorts and I'd like to see if there is anything I can do to properly fix the issue.

For the record, I have tried every option in the IB - adjust scroll view insets, extend edges under top/bottom bars, etc... as well as various code snippets I have googled here and there. Nothing seems to solve the issue for me.

I managed to solve the gap at the top of the table view under the nav bar (seemingly a common issue with a lot of content out there). But there does not seem to be so many cases like mine above.

Any help or indications are greatly appreciated. Thank you people :-)

*** ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ***

As per a comment below, I add the constraints I have tried for the said container:

[image]

Comment: Please show constraints you are using, especially for container.

Comment: Apologies, I should have added the constraints. Glad you pointed it out. I have been focusing on the 'bottom' constraint of the container, have left the top alone as I have no issue with the top alignment of the TableView.

Comment: I looked at your table view and saw space between it and view controller bottom. Could it be reason for this gap?

Comment: Sorry, that space was the bottom tab bar. I have amended the image accordingly.

Comment: Right, but you're unnecessarily using a container view in your tabbarcontroller, there is no way for your table view controller to infer it's in a tabbarviewcontroller. You want your table view controller to be flush with the bottom of the container view.

Comment: I would just directly embed your navigation controller in your tabbarviewcontroller and adjust the bottom inset of your table view.

Comment: Try to measure this gap - it's probably the same height as tab bar.

Comment: @beyowulf How can I embed the navigation controller in the tab bar controller? That's why I used the container. I need the table view controller as the root view controller of the navigation controller for my content flow.

Comment: I have figured it out - Editor > Embed in ... Tab Bar Controller. As you advised. Then to accommodate my banner view, where would I best present that?

Comment: Yes, I incorporate banner view in my table view controller. Excellent tip to change my structure. Please post it as an answer Sir.

Comment: Sorry, I had to step away from my computer. I don't have time to write up the  answer, also you did most of the work. Can you write an answer if you feel it will help others? You can accept it after 24 hours. Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Essentially, with the kind assistant of @beyowulf I realised my current setup had to be changed.

I was

> unnecessarily using a container view in your tabbarcontroller

as he correctly indicated

> there is no way for your table view controller to infer it's in a
>   tabbarviewcontroller.

In order for my table view controller to be flush with the bottom of the container view, I had to

> directly embed your navigation controller in your tabbarviewcontroller
>   and adjust the bottom inset of your table view.

I did this via the top menu bar items:

1. Select the TableViewController
2. Editor > Embed in - - - > Tab Bar Controller.

You can easily incorporate a navigation controller into the storyboard thereafter if you wish to do so, which I did also.

A handy tip and one I followed to solve my 'gap' issue appearing above the bottom tab bar.

Hope this helps anyone who might also be facing the same issue.

Thanks again to @beyowulf.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar gap problem, when used ContainerView to embed StoryboardReference - to support StoryboardReference from UITabBarController on iOS8.

I have resolved this by turning on Extended Egdes -> Under OpaqueBars checkbox on view controller with container view, like on image:

[image]

The red UIView is ContainerView, first ViewController in StoryboardReference is UINavigationController.